# Does anyone know what is the problem in this code? it's not work at all

Tags: c

I wrote this code and it's not working at all

I hope my explaining is good
.

So what I need from the "for" loop is to continue to the last condition  I had. and at the end print the counter number

```
{


//to do math
    float quarters = 0.25;
    float dimes  = 0.10;
    float nickels  = 0.5;
    float pennies  = 0.1;

//the number I need to transfer to 0
    float n = 0.65;

//the counting number
    int count = 0;
    
    for (;;)
    {
       if (n >= quarters ) // -0.25
        {
            n =  n - quarters;
            count += 1;
            return n ;
        }
        else if (n >= dimes) // -0.10
        {
            n =  n - dimes;
            count += 1;
            return n ;
        }
        else if (n >= nickels) // 0.5
        {
            n =  n - nickels;
            count += 1;
            return n ;
        }
        else if (n >= pennies) // 0.1
        {
            n =  n - pennies;
            count += 1;
            return n ;
        }
        else //return the counting number
        {
            printf("%i",count);
            break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is it supposed to do, and what happens instead?

Comment: just counting how much time u need to Transfer N to 0

Comment: What's with the `aaa...`s?

Comment: For "change" problems" please use integer values - work in cents. Please read [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency) `float dimes = 0.10;` cannot be *exactly* represented in binary to `int dimes = 10` can.

Comment: You cannot start a C code file with an open `{`.  Please, complete it to a [minimum, verifiable](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code that shows the observed problem (and describe what is the expected behaviour and the one you have instead)

Answer (score 3):

Do not `return n`, use `continue` instead - continue will tell your loop to go another round and that is what you want here in order to go through the conditional logic again.

`return` terminates your function, so your program exits before reaching the final else branch where you would print out the counter.

Also, your pennies are set as `0.1`, the same as dimes, and should be set to `0.01`, I assume.

EDIT:
Per comment of [Weather Vane](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4142924/weather-vane) posted under the question, it might be better to use integers for this problem, due to the misrepresentation of `0.01` in floating point. The SO question he has linked: [Why not use Double or Float to represent currency?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3730019/why-not-use-double-or-float-to-represent-currency)